# ASP.NET RADKit for Endeca

Tags: asp.net, rad, endeca

From where can the ASP.NET RADKit for Endeca downloaded from?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 15-Mar-2012, customers could download it from the [EDeN (Endeca Developer Network)](http://eden.endeca.com).  Since Oracle purchased Endeca in December of 2011, the download page now reads:

> "As of 15-Mar-2012, access to the Endeca Support Technical Notes and
>   previous product releases are no longer available through EDeN. The
>   Endeca Support Technical Notes have been migrated to My Oracle Support
>   and should be accessed there."

I would not recommend to use the RAD toolkit if you are going to implement any kind of website though! I have evaluated it and I have not found any way to build a site with a completely customized HTML layout. Use the normal presentation API, not the API delivered together with the RAD toolkit, and write your own wrapper around it.

Still, for an internal web-app the RAD controls might be just fine...

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://edelivery.oracle.com and login with your user account
2. Select "Oracle Endeca" as the Product Pack
3. Select "Microsoft Windows ... " as Platform
4. Click "Go" to search
5. In the results, select "Oracle Endeca Guided Search (6.x) Media Pack for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)"
6. Here you will find downloads for a number of components including "Oracle Endeca RAD Toolkit for ASP.NET 2.1.3 for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a customer in order to get access to their resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have found it difficult to find things on the EDeN site, it may be useful to have the actual link to the [Endeca RAD Toolkit for ASP.NET API Reference](http://eden.endeca.com/DocBrowser/rad21/210RADNET-API/Index.html)